# Изменение суммы заказа при нажатии на checkbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, checkbox

Задача следующая: сделать наценку на общую сумму заказа (Итого) на 20% при нажатии покупателя на checkbox, сейчас получается выводить только alert при нажатии на checkbox, но не получается изменить сумму. Взял код из интернета на добавление скидки, но пока и его не получается встроить. Либо подскажите плагин, который может реализовать это. Буду благодарен любой помощи!

**Файл cart.php**

```
<form action="">
    
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkFluency()" id="fluency"checked/> СРОЧНО
    
    
</form>
```

**Файл functions.php**

```
include 'https://new.kamelot.kz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php';
 
function woo_discount_total(WC_Cart $cart) {
?>
    <script>
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('fluency');{
         if (checkbox.checked != true){
    
        return;
        
    
</script>
<?php
    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.05; // 0.05 - это 5%
    
    $cart->add_fee('Фиксированная скидка в 5% ', -$discount);
 
}
 
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'woo_discount_total');
?>
<script>    
}
 
</script>
}
```

**То что получается сейчас:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `var checkbox = document.getElementById('fluency');{` что за открывающая скобка в конце строки? Где закрывающие скобки?

Comment: Закрывающая скобка находится в <script>